# `decltype` as part of template type specification within declaration of a template function

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, decltype

The [following code](http://ideone.com/zI3tv) compiles in MSVC++, but does not compile in GCC 4.5.1:

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename PT, bool pB >
struct TA
{
  PT m;
  TA( PT fT ) :
    m( fT )
  {
   std::cout << "TA<" << pB << ">::TA() : " << m << std::endl;
  }
  PT operator()( PT fT )
  {
   std::cout << "TA<" << pB << ">::() : " << m << " and " << fT << std::endl;
   return ( m );
  }
};

template< typename PT >
PT Foo( PT fT )
{
 std::cout << "Foo() : " << fT << std::endl;
 return ( fT );
}

// Does not compile in GCC 4.5.1, compiles in MSVC++2010. 
// Substitute TA< decltype( fF( std::forward<PP>( fP ) ) ), pB > with
// TA< double, pB > to compile with GCC.
template< bool pB, typename PF, typename PP >
auto Func( PF fF, PP && fP, TA< decltype( fF( std::forward<PP>( fP ) ) ), pB > && fA )
-> decltype( fF( std::forward<PP>( fP ) ) )
{
 decltype( fF( std::forward<PP>( fP ) ) ) lResult( fF( std::forward< PP >( fP ) ) );

 fA( lResult );

 return ( lResult );
}

int main( void )
{
 Func< true >( Foo< double >, -1.2, 2.1 );
 return ( 0 ); 
}
```

The comment points to the problematic line and shows the fix (which is not really a fix from design point of view, just a compilation fix). Few questions:

1. Is MSVC++ correct to compile this?
2. If we were to change parameters' order in

`auto Func( PF fF, PP && fP, TA< decltype( fF( std::forward<PP>( fP ) ) ), pB > && fA )`

to

`auto Func( PF fF, TA< decltype( fF( std::forward<PP>( fP ) ) ), pB > && fA, PP && fP )`

it would not compile, since compiler treats `fP` in `TA< decltype( fF( std::forward<PP>( fP ) ) ), pB >` as undeclared variable. Logically, does compiler really need to know `fP` at this point, does it not parse the whole declaration anyway, since it's function with trailing return-type? Why can it not "skip" second function parameter and see if `fP` is declared in function declaration later? Or I'm missing something fundamental here (perhaps, some paragraph from the Standard)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I believe MSVC is correct.
2. You cannot refer to a later parameter in the declaration of an earlier one, because the name is not yet in scope. In order to determine the type of your `fA` parameter, the both `fP` and `fF` must be in scope so that the `decltype` expression can be evaluated.

If you explicitly specify the template parameters then it works with gcc:

```
Func< true,decltype(&Foo<double>),double>( Foo< double >, -1.2, 2.1 );
```

That and the fact that specifying "double" directly as the parameter for `TA` works implies that the use of a dependent type for the `TA` parameter is preventing the type deduction for `PF` and `PP`. I can't see why that would be though.

Comment: I guess it's a problem with GCC then. I'm used to GCC being more advanced when it comes to language constructions, so I was a bit surprised. And nice "workaround" for GCC, by the way, it didn't occur for me to check.